# Failing to match directories using find -regex

Tags: regex, find

I have some directories under /var/log in the form of IP addresses i.e. 192.168.10.3

However the regex I have written is not matching them. Any clues?

```
find /var/log/ -type d -regex '/var/log/([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+'
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your regex to,

```
find /var/log/ -type d -regextype sed -regex ".*/\([0-9]\{1,3\}\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\+"
```

OR

```
find /var/log/ -type d -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/([0-9]+.){3}[0-9]+"
```

Comment: Note: All of the directories are of the form xx.xx.xx.xx 
Unfortunately the above does not work.

Comment: However do you know why my regex was not working? Is there a specific -regextype to set for it?

Comment: You need to specify the regex type. And also there is a problem in your regex , that is, `([0-9]\.){3}` would repeat a single digit plus a dot exactly three times. So it works only for the directories which has the name `1.1.1.187977`

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong regex.. mine had `([0-9]+\.){3}` yet still did not work. OK, cheers.

Comment: then the regex would be `".*/\([0-9]\+\.\)\{3\}[0-9]\+"`

Comment: @khadija if you have any problem in understanding the sed regex then you could use posix egrep regex. See my update.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative.